# How to remove XComments from XElement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I was hoping  to remove all of my XComment from the XElement before sending it to client.

from some reason it doesn't work and the removeMe.Count()=0

any thoughts?

```
{

   // ...

   myXml = XElement.Load(myPath);
   var removeMe=myXml.Descendants().Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment);
   removeMe.Count();        // this is 0 , (not what i was expected)
   removeMe.Remove();

   //...

   string myResponseStr = myXml.ToString(SaveOptions.None);
   context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
   context.Response.Write(myResponseStr);
 }
```

the xml file can be somthing like that

```
 <user>   
    <name> Elen </name>

    <userSettings>
       <color> blue  </color>                <!-- the theme color of the page -->
       <layout>  horizontal  </layout>      <!-- layout choise -->

       <!-- more settings -->

     </userSettings>

 </user>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [`DescendantNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendantnodes.aspx) instead of `Descendants`.

`Descendants` returns `XElement` instances, so it basically only returns the tags of your XML.
`DescendantNodes` returns `XNode` instances, which includes comments.

```
doc.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment).Remove();
```

Answer (score 9):

I would also use `DescendantNodes` but instead of the `Where` call it suffices to use `OfType<XComment>()` i.e. `doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XComment>().Remove()`.